# IE8 doesn't load background-image nor background-color CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have this style applied for a link:

```
#block-menu-menu-top-menu a.contact-us-link {
  background-image: url("../images/top-menu-contact.png") no-repeat;
  background-color: none;
  height: 28px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 34px;
}
```

IE8 loads only:

```
#block-menu-menu-top-menu a.contact-us-link {
  height: 28px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 34px;
}
```

What is this magic?

Comment: So the solution below worked and it loads now, but how, if background-image is not supported? And I chose that second example.

Comment: `background-image` is supported by IE8! But not multiple backgrounds  as CSS3 allows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background-image cannot have a repeat background property declared.

**shorthand background**

Note: you do not need to do url(""); url() - without quotes works as well.

```
[selector] {
  background: transparent url("../images/top-menu-contact.png") no-repeat;
}
```

**separate rules for each background CSS property.**

```
[selector] {
  background-image: url("../images/top-menu-contact.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```